# Android permissions not being shown and onRequestPermissionResults running infinite times

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a method in the onCreate where I ask for 2 permissions and I have onRequestPermissionResults set up such that if any of the 2 permissions are denied the method that asks for permissions should be called again.

But what is happening is if I deny any permission for the 1st time then the method to ask permission is called again but if i deny any permission second time then the onRequestPermissionResults method calls the method infinitely and i dont get any popup for asking permission.

Here is the code of the permission asking method

```
private fun requestAllPermission(oncreate: String) {
    //requesting permissions
    Log.d("permissions",oncreate)
    if(!checkSMSPermission(this) || !checkLocationPermission(this)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALL)
    }
    //checkBackgroundLocation()
}
```

Here is the onPermissionRequestMethod

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if(requestCode== PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALL){
        if(grantResults.isNotEmpty()){
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || grantResults[2]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permissions Required to Operate.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                //again request permission
                requestAllPermission("after")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is The refernce for the error being shown, the oncreate tag means the method is called by onCreate() AND after tag means the method was called by onRequestPermissionResult

Log when method called by oncreate on first launch of app

2023-06-02 14:04:30.670 30781-30781 permissions             com.chrizlove.helpapp                D  oncreate

Log when I denied permissions and permissions are asked again

2023-06-02 14:04:38.735 30781-30781 permissions             com.chrizlove.helpapp                D  after

Now when I denied permissions 2nd time no permissions ask dialog is being
shown on app and the method is called infintely

2023-06-02 14:04:46.104 30781-30781 permissions             com.chrizlove.helpapp                D  after

2023-06-02 14:04:46.179 30781-30781 permissions             com.chrizlove.helpapp                D  after

2023-06-02 14:04:46.248 30781-30781 permissions             com.chrizlove.helpapp                D  after

2023-06-02 14:04:46.300 30781-30781 permissions             com.chrizlove.helpapp                D  after

2023-06-02 14:04:46.367 30781-30781 permissions             com.chrizlove.helpapp                D  after

it runs infinitely

I also want to say that this problem was not present on emulator but only on physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

When you deny a permission. You cannot again ask for permission using requestPermissions you have to go to settings of the app and then allow permissions from there.

So what I think is happening is that when you deny permission for the first time the requestPermissions/requestAllPermissions function has atleast one permission to ask. So it runs one time, but when you deny the second permission it has no permissions remaining to ask for since all of them are denied so it runs the onRequestPermissionsResult which in itself is again calling the requestAllPermissions function but since all of the requests are denied it will not show you any dialog box to enable or disable permissions and again call the onRequestPermissionsResult and this will keep happening

It was happening even before you denied all permissions the only difference is that you were seeing an alert box to enable disable permission because there is one remaining permission to ask for

Basically this is not the correct method to do this
So what you should do is if you want both of the permissions to be true then show an alert box when both the permissions are denied that will take the user to the app settings or show a toast that tells the user that app will work only if both permissions are enabled (or whatever your logic is), do this rather than recursively calling the requestAllPermissions function

your onRequestPermissionsResult should look something like this:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if(requestCode== PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALL){
        if(grantResults.isNotEmpty()){
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || grantResults[2]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permissions Required to Operate.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                //dont request permission again
                // display a toast or an dialog box as mentioned above

            }
        }
    }
}
```